# Testing member assignment using mocks in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am writing a testing framework for my system, which allows users to create mocked inputs to the system. The system manipulates that input, and updates some of its members for later post processing.

In order to allow users to mock the input, I need to be able to update a mocked input's members. Furthermore, the input may not be a mock, so I would prefer a solution oblivious to the type of element received.

Simply put, I have a function which receives an object and attempts to set one of its properties:

```
func(object a)
a.m = 5;
```

Which I want to test by mocking its input a, using the Moq library. Unfortunately, my test failed, since mocked objects' members need to be set using `Mock.SetUpGet`, instead of standard member assignment.

What would be a good way to test such a function, without changing it?

Comment: I don't know the Moq library, but it would be possible to create a property "M" and the implementation of this property in the mocking class would call the Mock.SetUpGet?

Comment: I think you example needs to be a little more detailed. As it is currently, it is broad. Give a sample object. don't know of `m` is a field or property, whether a is actual `object` or some other derived type. It would greatly improve the quality of answers you can get

Comment: @Nkosi is right, we need more details to answer your question; I'll elaborate, by reading your question I feel that a is a PoCo object... If so you don't need to mock it at all...

Comment: @Nkosi and Old Fox - I am writing a testing framework for my system, which allows users to create mocked inputs to the system. The system manipulates that input, and updates some of its members for later post processing.

In order to allow users to mock the input, I need to be able to update a mocked input's members.
Furthermore, the input may not be a mock, so I would prefer a solution oblivious to the type of element received.

Comment: @yuvalm2 you should include that last comment in the question to give background to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to mock and test it, the property must be `virtual`, but if that's the case you can use the `SetupSet` method, rather than `SetupGet`:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int m { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{

    public static void SetProperty(A a)
    {
        a.m = 5;
    }

    [Test]
    public void IsThePropertySet()
    {
        var x = new Mock<A>();
        x.SetupSet<int>(a => a.m = 5).Verifiable();
        SetProperty(x.Object);
        x.Verify();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should have getters and setters anyway.

And a good way of testing whether your functions work is to do a small-scale test. Initialize an object and send that in to your method, seeing whether it does what you want.

```
 public class myClass
    {
        public int number;
        public void setNumber(int nNum)
        {
            number = nNum;
        }
        public int getNumber()
        {
            return number;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void myMethod(myClass obj, int nNumb)
        {
            //obj.setNumber(nNumb);
            obj.number = nNumb;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myClass myObj = new myClass();
            myMethod(myObj, 3);
            //Console.WriteLine(myObj.getNumber());
            Console.WriteLine(myObj.number);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }       
    }
}
```

Output: `3`

Comment: That may be a solution, but since I already have numerous users using that interface without implementing such a setter function, I would prefer not to break that interface.

Comment: Well if you don't want to use setters, you'd have to make the item `public` so that it could be accessed from anywhere. That way you can just go `myObj.number = nNumb;` or `a.m = 5;` in your case.
I've edited the answer to show what I mean.